# Why does my phone enable camera shutter sounds whenever I insert an Indian SIM?

Tags: india, international-travel, cellphones, mobile-operators

I travel a lot, and one of the places I visit frequently is India. As a result, I usually carry SIM cards from the places I spend the most time in. Whenever I insert an Indian SIM card into my phone, the phone camera starts playing a shutter sound whenever I take a picture. This takes place on all apps on my phone that use the camera, from the default camera app to Instagram and Snapchat. This takes place in all phone modes and volume settings, including in airplane mode.

When a US or UK SIM card is inserted, the camera is silent and does not make the same noise when a photo is taken. I have noticed that this takes place with SIM cards of all operators in India, and this seems to have been the case for at least the last 2 years. I believe this is related to some legal requirement in India. The only thing I've found about this is a similar thing happening in Japan, as per this [TripAdvisor forum thread](https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowTopic-g298184-i861-k10949455-Disabling_phone_camera_shutter_sound-Tokyo_Tokyo_Prefecture_Kanto.html).

**Does anyone know why inserting an Indian SIM card into a phone activates an impossible to disable camera shutter sound?**

Comment: This is a legal requirement in some countries. The same thing happens in Japan and from the answers, also in Korea.

Comment: Plenty of questions about this on [android.se], most of [these](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+shutter+sound) mention the legal requirements.

Comment: Not an answer to the "why", but if you root your phone, the sound is easily fixed by finding and removing the `.ogg` file. I used to do this on older Android versions that lacked an option to turn off the shutter sound.

Comment: @R.. The question then becomes, if you do that in a country where it's legally mandated and law enforcement finds out how much trouble are you going to end up in.

Comment: @DanNeely: Seems unlikely unless you were actually doing something bad with the camera. Don't frame it as "I did this to get around country-specific rules". Frame it as "oh, my phone's never made a shutter sound, it's a US/UK/whatever model and we don't have any regulation like that".

Comment: @R. that is exactly why the SIM card enforces it - if you actively work around it, there could easily be an assumption of ill intent - in the worst case, of harassment or espionage.

Comment: @rackandboneman: The SIM card can't enforce it; it's not controlling the speaker or anything about the computer. It can just tell the software a flag, and it's up to the software what to do with that flag. If a particular local phone model doesn't even have a shutter sound there's no way it's going to make one just because of a flag on the SIM.

Comment: Given that most functionality on a modern smartphone is realized in software, a software flag is as good as controlling it. And software that hasn't been intentionally altered will honor the flag, no?

Comment: What prevents someone even not that technologically advanced, to just kill/extract/damage/short circuit the speaker on an old mobile phone, and carrying it around for photos? That is not a technological problem, it is a people problem.

Comment: I wonder if Apple products make noise as well in these countries.

Comment: Which phone do you have? See my answer for some of the vendors that have fixed this bug

Comment: If you're an Android do yourself a favour and install an alternative firmware such as LineageOS. This will fix a lot of grievances you might have with your phone.

Comment: @Kyslik in Korea they do.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin You're right, it's a bit confusing for me as well. I've changed the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't find any evidence of any law in India that mandates a camera shutter sound. Indeed in this bug fix for the Oneplus 5, the shutter sound in silent mode in India was fixed:

https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/oxygenos-4-5-7-ota-for-oneplus-5.587514/

> Bug Fixes:
>
> - Fixed occasional sound leaks in the speakers when using earphones
> - **Fixed camera shutter sound bug in silent mode for Indian region**
> - Fixed missing sound channels when recording videos

If your phone makes a shutter sound in silent mode in India, I would file a bug with your smartphone vendor.

Some other vendors who've fixed this **bug**:
https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1031837/

> **In India, the sound of camera’s shutter is permanently ON because of
> Google’s original design**, even if you’ve switched off the shutter
> sound in camera settings. H**owever, we will change this option so users
> are able to normally turn on/off camera shutter sound in the future
> update**.
>
> Because of local government regulations, if you purchased
> your phone in either Japan or South Korea, the Camera sound option is
> not shown on Camera settings and the shutter sound will be ON even if
> you use your device in other countries.

https://nokiapoweruser.com/turn-off-camera-shutter-sound-nokia-android-smartphones/

> In this tutorial, we will let you know how to turn off camera shutter
> sound on Nokia Android smartphones Nokia 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 and 8. By
> default, the Nokia Android smartphones come with camera shutter sound
> on.
>
> Update: This works on Nokia 6 India variant too after installing the
> Oreo Beta update.
>
> While in some of the markets it is a legal requirement and
> manufacturers including HMD can’t provide an option to disable this
> shutter sound, **in other markets including India it can be turned off**.

https://beebom.com/googles-february-update-pixel-2-camera-sounds/

> Google Pixel 2 February **Update Allows Indian Users to Turn off Camera
> Sounds**

Comment: Which makes me wonder, why it was enabled for the India region to begin with. Also in my case, it seems to be the issue with the SIM card, since (on a recent flight) I was still in the UK, but just put an Indian SIM in the phone.

Comment: @crayarikar Possibly it was just a mistake that got promulgated, or Indian telecoms companies voluntarily decided to set whatever the SIM flag for enforcing a shutter sound is

Comment: Potentially. What is also interesting is that Indian law requires SIM cards to be deactivated if they're inactive for more than 3 months. And when I reached India, I did find out that my SIM card was deactivated. So the settings are probably pre loaded on the SIM.

Comment: Indian Criminal Law Amendment (2013) Section 354C, and Information Technology Act 2000, Section 66E; the settings aren't loaded in the SIM, they are activated by the device when the SIM operator country code is one of those countries where privacy laws dictate that permission must be obtained before taking pictures. The actual restriction is embedded in the software of the device.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Where in that does it mandate a shutter sound? I don't see it

Comment: It doesn't - but the shutter sound is explicit intent, especially as cellphone cameras are often used for voyeurism and other possible privacy violations. In Japan, for example, the Anti Nuisance Ordinance (which covers many things, including taking pictures of people) is what is used to enforce loud shutters on camera phones.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Both 354C and 66E are explictly about punishment. There's nothing to do with technological enforcement in either of those two statutes.

Comment: @Berwyn One can't tell from the text of the release notes you quoted exactly what the bug was. You interpret it to mean that they fixed a bug where shutter-sound was being made while the device was in silent mode. I interpret it to mean the perfect opposite: The bug was that an exploit to bypass the mandatory shutter-sound was possible, just by putting the device into silent mode.

Comment: @Beanluc https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/one-plus-5-has-shutter-sound-issue-while-taking-video-or-photo.580021/#post-16588061 The people who use this phone said the bug was fixed in that thread and it no longer makes a shutter sound after 4.5.7

Answer (score 31):

This happens with Korean SIM cards too, so I suspect this is a similar case: in Korea there have been too many upskirt photos scandals, and the government imposed a shutter sound when photos are taken, so that people are aware a photo is taken, possibly by someone malicious.

I suspect the same thing happened in India.